# Change the mouse double-click response area

Tags: linux, double-click

Is there a way to increase the double-click area tolerance in Linux? My double clicks get ignored because of the subtle movements of my mouse while double-clicking.

My current system is ubuntu 17.10 x64 (Gnome)